# SpringSecurity do not forward to https

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Dear All,
                  
 We have added Spring Security for our web application. Login url seems like this

https://www.xyz.com/app/login.do

after login it should redirect to other urls with same https protocol. Right now SpringSecurity redirect us to other urls but with http not https.

Please tell us any specific settings are needed.

Thanks,
Op

Answer (score 0):

Within your spring security definitions, inside your `intercept-url` tag you need to add `requires-channel="https"`

For example:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check*" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="https" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and comments on my question. Let me try it. If it will work I will accept your answer.